# Semantic mark for testimonial details

Tags: css, html

I jus got the following PSD design:

[image]
(sorry about the grid line in between , that blue line really is not needed.).

Now i was wondering with all there html5 tags , what would be a great and semantic markup to code the above design , iám usually a guy who goes old school and uses `div` and `spans` , but this time i used `cite` , when i read the MDN doc's there seems to still be no clarity weather a name/designation can be used in `cite` , basically the way look at cite is , it a tag to be used only when you have a definitive resource to be added to you markup. Even though neither name nor designation is a definitive resource, i came up with the following markup.

```
<div class="testimonia-details">

        <img src="img/res/p1.png" alt="testimonial giver">
        <p>
            <span>Brian</span>-May 2015
            <span>Managing Partner.<cite>Tammy Lenski LLC</cite></span>
        </p>

</div>
```

can anybody tell me what would be a more semantic way to code the testimonial details ? Thank you , i would greatly appreciate any help or guidance, i have always wonder what would be a semantic markup especially for a scenario like above.

Comment: I wouldn't use `cite` as it's more usually associated with blockquotes or quotes (this example is neither) but you could always use [schema.org](https://schema.org/Person) microdata to add semantic richness.

Comment: @KarlDawson thanks , i am also thinking about the figure and figcaption element for the about sort of testimonial thing !

Comment: If the `figure` block makes sense when placed elsewhere (i.e. it has it's own context), then sure you could probably do that. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) has an example where a poem is marked up using `figure`, so it's not just limited to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using schema.org metadata

```html
<div class="testimonia-details" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <img src="img/res/p1.png" alt="testimonial giver" itemprop="image">
  <p>
    <span itemprop="name">Brian</span>-May 2015
    <span itemprop="jobTitle">Managing Partner.<span itemprop="worksFor">Tammy Lenski LLC</span></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks lovely , i wanted an opinion more about the HTML tags thats i've used though , but nice answer !

Comment: :) Go for the `figure` / `figcaption` route (or both even).